# How to throw an exception if required properties have either null or empty values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to throw an exception when I parse the received object to a DTO and while parsing if any of the fields in DTO that I have marked as required has null values then I want to throw an exception with 400 response.

I have a controller like this,

```
public class StandardController(@RequestBody Object body) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();  
    try {
      CustomDTO customDto = modelMapper.map(body, CustomDTO.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //throw exception with a message required properties are missing with 400 response`
    }
}
```

I have marked a few properties in my CustomDTO as `required = true` with `JsonProperty`. But when I test the controller, its not throwing an exception.

Any idea how I can implement this scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure you posted the correct code chunk b/c `public class StandardController()` does not compile. I'm guessing this was meant to be the method?

Comment: It is a controller with an endpoint that receives requests from external api.

Comment: Right I understand your intention, but if you actually paste your code the way it is into an IDE it won't even compile which is why i was assuming you copied it into stack overflow wrong.

Comment: I just copied it as a placeholder similar to what I am doing in a real code because real code is bigger and contains unnecessary stuff.

Comment: To be more clear, your first line: `public class StandardController(@RequestBody Object body) {` is not valid Java. I think you meant for this line to be a method, but instead you put `class` in the method definition accidently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to receive CustomDto directly from the user. Because DTO is meant for transfer. If you receive custom dto from user then you can add validation on the object.

Just an example

```
@Data
public class ClassDto {

    private Long classId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 200)
    private String className;

    private Double classAdmissionFee;
}
```

Look at the @NotNull and @Size annotation. They comes under javax validation.

Now once after your DTO is fully configured. You need to do this:

```
public class StandardController(@Valid @RequestBody CustomDTO customDto) {
    
}
```

Notice the @Valid annotation. While any of the DTO constraints fails spring will throw a MethodArgumentNotValidException. So you need to handle the exception via @ControllerAdvice or extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

Here is a nice article link for your case:
https://www.javaguides.net/2021/04/spring-boot-dto-validation-example.html

Comment: So I tried this and request still went through. However, when i tried with lombok's `@NonNull` then request successfully threw 400. But I would still like to find a way to do it with `@NotNull` since it allows to send a custom message.

Comment: did you have spring boot validation dependency in your pom.xl? and make sure @Notnull coming from javax.

Comment: Yeah that was it. Its working now. Thanks! Any idea how I can write junit test to check for status code? I did write one but it returns 200 instead of 400 and test case fails. But when I call the API endpoint through postman I get 400 as it should.

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Boot controller, you can use [ResponseStatusException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html).
Something like this should work:

```
try {
  //Your Code here
} catch(Exception e) {
  throw new ResponseStatusException( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Required properties are missing");
}
```

Also, you can check [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception) on Baeldung if you want more information about this way of exception handling.